# What is an efficient way to fetch matrix elements from index sets in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have some matrix

```
x <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
```

and I want to fetch certain elements of the matrix whose row and column indices are mentioned in two different sets like:

```
i1 <- c(2, 3, 5, 7)
i2 <- c(1, 7, 9)
```

Now my function should return the elements at position (2, 1), (3, 1), ..., (5, 9), (7, 9). i.e. `i1` contains the row indices and `i2` contains column indices.

Comment: To grab a submatrix, `x[i1, i2]`

Comment: Have you started to write something at least?

Comment: A dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617371/getting-elements-of-a-matrix-with-vectors-of-coordinates

Comment: I'm guessing there is a dupe, but if they're after the submatrix, that is not the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
x[as.matrix(expand.grid(i1, i2))]
[1]  2  3  5  7 62 63 65 67 82 83 85 87
```

Comment: Nice to hear from you :-)

Comment: Thanks sir. It was very helpful.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thanks! :-)

Comment: Or `c(x[i1, i2])`. Blame Frank :)

Answer (score 2):

To grab a submatrix:

```
x[i1, i2]
```

If you want it as a vector, wrap in `c()`. This also works if `i1` and `i2` are logical vectors or vectors of row and column names. See `help("[")` for full documentation.

Comment: Figured I ought to post the right way, for posterity / whoever comes across this later.