# I have a 3-dimensional array in R. How can I (efficiently) select elements along the second and third dimension jointly?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 3-dimensional array in R, let's call it `A`. I want to transform the array into a 2-dimensional array, `B`, in the following way:

1. The first dimension of `B` should correspond to the first dimension of `A`.
2. The second dimension of `B` should made up of selected elements along `A`'s 2nd and 3rd dimensions.

I have two vectors indicating the second and third indices of A to be selected along B's second dimension, let's call them `v_2` and `v_3`.

If A is `n` by `m` by `k`, and v_2 and v_3 have length `l`, then `B` therefore takes the form of a `n` by `l` matrix where row `i` is given by `A[i,v_2[j],v_3[j]]` for `j=1:l`.

I want to be as efficient as possible, since in my application v_2 and v_3 are very long.

Without the first dimension, the problem boils down to the one solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617371/getting-elements-of-a-matrix-with-vectors-of-coordinates). How can I solve the case where I want to maintain the first dimension?

Comment: It will be much easier for people to give relevant help if you can share code that shows a simple version of this, or if performance is of primary concern, which generates replicable data (e.g. using `set.seed()`) that is the scale of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 1629065761
set.seed(seed)

n <- 3L
m <- 4L
k <- 6L
a <- array(1:(n*m*k), c(n, m, k))
(v_2 <- sample(m, m - 1, 1))
#> [1] 2 3 4
(v_3 <- sample(k, m - 1, 1))
#> [1] 5 5 2
```

Option 1 - element indexing. Extract elements from `a` based on their index from `1:(n*m*k)`.

```
matrix(a[rep(1:n, each = length(v_2)) + n*(rep(v_2, n) - 1L) + n*m*(rep(v_3, n) - 1L)], n, length(v_2), 1)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   52   55   22
#> [2,]   53   56   23
#> [3,]   54   57   24
```

Option 2 - index using a matrix of dimensions `n`-by-`3`. Each row represents the 3D index of a single element.

```
matrix(a[matrix(c(rep(1:n, each = length(v_2)), rep(v_2, n), rep(v_3, n)), n*length(v_2), 3)], n, length(v_2), 1)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   52   55   22
#> [2,]   53   56   23
#> [3,]   54   57   24
```

Option 1 will be slightly faster, as the index vector is 1/3 the size of the index matrix in Option 2.

```
n <- 300L
m <- 400L
k <- 600L
a <- array(1:(n*m*k), c(n, m, k))
v_2 <- sample(m, m - 1, 1)
v_3 <- sample(k, m - 1, 1)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  elem = matrix(a[rep(1:n, each = length(v_2)) + n*(rep(v_2, n) - 1L) + n*m*(rep(v_3, n) - 1L)], n, length(v_2), 1),
  matrix = matrix(a[matrix(c(rep(1:n, each = length(v_2)), rep(v_2, n), rep(v_3, n)), n*length(v_2), 3)], n, length(v_2), 1),
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>    elem 2.0509 2.13525 2.439793 2.18890 2.26740 24.6545   100
#>  matrix 2.2474 2.33730 2.661697 2.39025 2.47115 25.9698   100
```